# How to change AWS Amplify Appsync default authorization mode form API KEY to cognito user pool?

Tags: graphql, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

I'm working with **Amplify**, I added the authentication to my application and my graphQL schema is with rule private, all things work good in my local, each graphQl api called, It contains the ***access token*** and appSync accept my request.
But when I deploy my App, I get an error because all my graphQl request still with **api-key** not with access token.

**my schema.graphQl**
[image]

**My AWSAppSyncClient**
[image]

***In the console I use this configuration***:
[image]

***In my local :*** all thins work good after authentication.

[image]

***In production :*** graphQl still with api-key after authentication

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Based on this [documentation](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/graphqlapi/authz/q/platform/ios/#aws-lambda) I ran `amplify update api`:

From there the command line prompts you to select the API type:

```
? Please select from one of the below mentioned services:
    > `GraphQL`
? Select a setting to edit:
    > `Authorization modes`
? Choose the default authorization type for the API
  API key
  Amazon Cognito User Pool
❯ IAM
  OpenID Connect
```

I updated the default authorization type for the API to be `Amazon Cognito User Pool` instead of `API key`.

Then I had to run `amplify push --appId YOUR_APP_ID --envName YOUR_STAGING_ENV` to sync up the changes.

Comment: Thanks for this. I saw your answer on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73141849/aws-amplify-unauthorized-error-not-authorized-to-access-on-type/73141885#comment132695779_73141885