# AWS Amplify Unauthorized Error - Not Authorized to access [...] on type [...]

Tags: aws-amplify

I have an AWS Amplify app using google federate sign in.
This is my data model.

```
type TriadeMetric @model @auth(rules: [{allow: owner}]) {
  id: ID!
  NoteMetrics: [NoteMetric] @hasMany(indexName: "byTriadeMetric", fields: ["id"])
}

enum MetricEnum {
  ACCURACY
  DURATION
}

type NoteMetric @model @auth(rules: [{allow: owner}]) {
  id: ID!
  metricType: MetricEnum
  value: Float
  triademetricID: ID! @index(name: "byTriadeMetric")
  semitones: Int
}
```

When I try to create a new record using

```
const triadeMetric = await DataStore.save(new TriadeMetric({}));
```

I got this warning message:

`[{"errorType":"Unauthorized","message":"Not Authorized to access onCreateTriade on type Triade"}]}`

and this error:

`{"errors":[{"errorType":"Unauthorized to access onCreateTriade on type Triade"}]}`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I was using the wrong authentification type:
In aws-exports.js
I replaced `"aws_appsync_authenticationType": "API_KEY"`
with `"aws_appsync_authenticationType": "AMAZON_COGNITO_USER_POOLS"`

Comment: Changing the AWS AppSync AuthenticationType ended up working for me. But in my case my aws-exports.js had a warning that prevented me from editing the file directly"// WARNING: DO NOT EDIT. This file is automatically generated by AWS Amplify. It will be overwritten." The steps here https://stackoverflow.com/a/74235681/6417947 was what I had to do instead to change the authentication type.

Comment: amplify api update might do the trick

Comment: After hours of banging my head against the wall, this did the trick. Thank you!

Amplify makes it very difficult to know what is synced between backend and app. :(

Answer (score 2):

I ran below command:

```
amplify api update
```

under authorization mode, I picked: Amazon Cognito User Pool
Then after I ran below command:

```
amplify push -y
```

After the deployment, I reloaded the app and now it works!